# My Pokemon changed after caught?

Tags: pokemon-go

So, this day I caught Raticate, Goldeen, and Grimer. But after I caught them all, they're suddenly change to completely different Pokemon.

My Raticate turns into Exeggcute, Goldeen into Spearow, and Grimer into Ratatta. Is this a glitch from new update?

Comment: If it happened, then probably yes, but that seems like a very unlikely thing to happen.

Comment: @Dragonrage Yeah, and Grimer is not registered on my pokedex yet, when finally caught it, it turns into another Ratatta

Comment: And, just when I thought Niantic couldn't mess up worse then they already had. I didn't hear of this happening prior to the update, nor did I experience it myself, so I would suggest opening a ticket with their support, or reporting it to them.

Comment: @Dragonrage Well, I think this happening after the updates, before I updated, all okay when I caught pokemon

Comment: Downvote? What's wrong with my question?

Comment: Have you looked in the Journal? what does it say you caught?

Comment: iOS or android?

Comment: @Dragonrage from the journal, I've caught Exeggcute, Spearow, and Ratatta, none of them are the correct one.

Comment: @vynsane I'm using Android

Comment: This is highly disconcerting. What version of android, what hardware, etc...

Comment: @vynsane Android 6.0.1 on Asus Zenfone 2 Laser Ze500KL, Pokemon GO version 0.31.0. So far, only that three that changed after I caught, until now it's fine when I caught it.

Comment: Its a glitch. Someone caught a Pokemon and it turned into an Articuno. Source: Facebook trending news.

Comment: raticate into moltres would have been cool too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the current version ([see this german blog](http://derstandard.at/2000042322602/Pokemon-Go-Entwickler-loeschen-legendaere-Monster-aus-Spieleraccounts)). It's not said, wheter only iOS or Android is affected, but for a small amount of players it is possible that they can get a different (also the legendary Arctuino) Pokémon than they caught.
Niantic should have fixed this and removed the wrongly distributed Arctuino from the accounts.
To now there is no known trigger of the effect.